# adding script to which command

Tags: linux, bash, which

I have a script/tool in linux `/full/path/here/grabber`.
I want to know how I will be able to use `which` on it. So every time i want to use it, I can just execute `grabber` instead of having to call its full path. I also would like to see its full path whenever I issue `which grabber`.

```
 $which grabber
 /full/path/here/grabber
```

Comment: Either (1) add `/full/path/here` to your `$PATH` variable, or (2) create a softlink from `grabber` to some place that is already in your `$PATH` like `sudo ln -s /full/path/here/grabber /usr/bin/grabber`.

Comment: it worked! Thanks!

Comment: In some distros if you have a "~/bin" directory, it is automatically added to your PATH. This is a good place to put personal scripts.

Comment: @xenoid Do you know which distributions add `~/bin` to the `PATH` _automatically_?  There are many times when I would like to recommend `~/bin` but I've found that the  complications associated with adding `~/bin` to the `PATH` can easily frustrate new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Add `/full/path/here` to your `$PATH` variable.

or,

2. Create a softlink from grabber to some place that is already in your `$PATH` like `sudo ln -s /full/path/here/grabber /usr/bin/grabber`.